# How to mock IEnumerable in AddClaimsAsync method in order to run a unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, claims

I need to Mock the `AddClaimsAsync()` method which is this one here. I have an issue with the `IEnumerable`. After reading I found out that if I mock an object and then add it to a Collection it should work.:

```
public async Task<IdentityResult> AddClaimsAsync(IntentUser user, IEnumerable<Claim> claims)
{
    return await this.userManager.AddClaimsAsync(user, claims);
}
```

Here is the test:

```
var itemMock = new Mock<Claim>();
var items = new List<Claim> {itemMock.Object};
userManagerWrapperMock.Setup(u => u.AddClaimsAsync(admin, items)).ReturnsAsync(admin, new[]
{
    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, dto.FirstName),
    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.GivenName, dto.FirstName),
    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName, dto.FamilyName),
    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, dto.Email),
    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.EmailVerified, dto.EmailConfirmed.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Boolean)
});
```

This is the method in the Controller that needs to be mocked:

```
await userManagerWrapper.AddClaimsAsync(usr, new[]
{
    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, userDto.FirstName),
    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.GivenName, userDto.FirstName),
    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName, userDto.FamilyName),
    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.EmailVerified, user.EmailConfirmed.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Boolean)
});
```

The error I get is:

> '`ISetup<IUserManagerWrapper, Task<IdentityResult>>`' does not contain a
>   definition for '`ReturnsAsync`' and the best extension method overload
>   '`ReturnsExtensions.ReturnsAsync<IUserManagerWrapper,
>   IntentUser>(IReturns<IUserManagerWrapper, ValueTask<IntentUser>>,
>   IntentUser, TimeSpan)`' requires a receiver of type
>   '`IReturns<IUserManagerWrapper, ValueTask<IntentUser>>`'

Comment: `ReturnsAsync()` should be passed the thing you want the mocked method to return. So instead of that weird return call (`admin, new[] ...`), do you simply mean: `ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Success)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not need to return anything, it was a void method.

Also I did not need to Mock anything. Simply this works.

```
        userManagerWrapperMock.Setup(u => u.AddClaimsAsync(admin, new[]
        {
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, dto.FirstName),
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.GivenName, dto.FirstName),
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName, dto.FamilyName),
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, dto.Email),
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.EmailVerified, dto.EmailConfirmed.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Boolean)
        }));
```

Comment: It is not a void method, it returns `Task<IdentityResult>`, which will now return `null` (assuming `MockBehavior.Default` or `Loose`), which will throw if you inspect the result in the call site (`var result = await userManager.AddClaimsAsync()`).